# EntrySet method implementation in Hashtable

Tags: java

I'm working on implementation of Hashtable. There is a method entrySet() which will return **set** of Map.entry. When I put this method in System.out.println() method I see string that looks something like this [key=value]. I want to make the same method. I have used the code below but the result looks much different from the one above. Just many references to 
HashEntry classes and not values with keys. What can I do to reach what I want?

```
public Set<HashEntry> entrySet(){
        Set<HashEntry> set = new AbstractSet<HashEntry>(){
            @Override
            public Iterator<HashEntry> iterator(){
                return new Iterator<HashEntry>(){

                    int pos = 0;

                    @Override                    
                    public boolean hasNext(){
                        return globalArray.length>pos;
                    }

                    @Override                    
                    public HashEntry next(){
                        return globalArray[pos++];
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void remove() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot remove an element of an array.");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String toString(){
                        return globalArray[pos].getValue() + "=" + globalArray[pos].getKey();
                    }

                };
            }

            @Override 
            public int size(){
                return size;
            }
        };
        return set;
    }
```

HashEntry class:

```
public class HashEntry{
    private int key;
    private Object value;

    public HashEntry(int key, Object value){
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }

    public Object getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public void setKey(int key){
        this.key = key;
    }

}
```

Comment: You haven't shown us your `HashEntry` class, which is going to be the main thing to change.

Comment: @louis-wasserman Ooops! You are right. Thanks. I have edited my question. Please, take a look.

Comment: "_What can I do to reach what I want_" Add a toString() method in the `HashEntry` class.

Comment: @csm-dev I have tried it previously but it didn't work as I expected. I also have edited my question and added toString method - the one that I used. But again, it didn't work. May be it is written wrongly?

Comment: @csm_dev said you needed a `toString` in `HashEntry`, not in the set implementation.  They are correct.

Comment: @csm_dev Thank you. I got it.

Comment: @louis-wasserman Thanks! Got it.